# SWRevealViewController: fetch content from different urls in same ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, menu, navigation

I am trying to make a blog reader app with the categories of the blog listed in the side navigation menu/slide out menu. I am following this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/). The tutorial statically links all the menu items to their respective ViewControllers.

I want all my categories to open in the NewsTableViewController only as duplication of news controller wld be a very bad idea.

My current viewDidLoad method for NewsTableViewController is this:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }

    categoryUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.techmuzz.com/news/api/get_recent_posts/")!
    
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: categoryUrl!)
    tableView.hidden = true
    
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(categoryUrl!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        //   println("Task completed")
        if(error != nil) {
            // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        var err: NSError?
        
        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
        if(err != nil) {
            // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
            println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
        }
        let results: NSArray = jsonResult["posts"] as NSArray
        self.didReceiveResults(jsonResult)

        
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

This loads the recent posts in the NewsTableViewController. Now, there is another category, say, News which has url `http://www.techmuzz.com/api/get_recent_posts/?json=get_category_posts&slug=news-2`which is added in the side navigation menu. How do i pass its url so that it gets loaded in the same NewsTableViewController.

Can some one please help me figure out how can this be done. I thank you in advance

Comment: can u add some more information

Comment: i partially understand ur ?, initially the default url is loaded, when the categories is change u need to call this URL correct

Comment: I have used this url for demo purpose. Yes, i need to replace this default url with that of the selected category

Comment: k simple add one more condition when u select the cell (sidemenu) add one substring and in your main controller check the condition both are equal call the new web service else old one, got it